# Data output in the specific scientific form

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, output

If I have data of

```
data = Table[f[x,y],{x,{1,2}},{y,{1,2}}]
```

which gives

> {{f[1,1],f[1,2]},{f[2,1],f[2,2]}}

Then Export["file.txt",data,"Table"] gives

```
f[1, 1]   f[1, 2]
f[2, 1]   f[2, 2]
```

f[i,j] is a real number, and I would like to output it in the following form:

> (sign)(number in 4 precision)(E)(sign of E)(powers of E)

For instance, if the number is
1120.14, I want it to be expressed as +1.120E+03 
and if the number is -0.0315377, I want it expressed as -3.153E-02.

Is this possible?
Also, when I use NumberForm, the output looks as list

> {{f[1,1],f[1,2]},{f[2,1],f[2,2]}}

Answer (score 4):

### Rounding

I'm going to first assume that you really want the precision you claimed, 4 digits, as opposed to a hard truncation like your example, which is a nice out of box application of `NumberForm`:

```
format[num_] := 
 NumberForm[num, {4, 3}, 
  ExponentFunction -> (If[-1 < # < 1, Null, #] &), 
  NumberFormat -> (SequenceForm[#1, "E", #3] &), 
  NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]

applyFormatting[expr_] := expr /. a_ :> format[a] /; NumberQ[a]

tab1 = {{5.6^10, 7.8^20}, {1120.14, -0.0315377}} // 
  applyFormatting;
```

Yields:

```
{{+3.033E7, +6.949E17}, {+1.120E3, -3.154E-2}}
```

Notice the formatting is applied to the numbers themselves not to the table. So `Export` and `TableForm` should work as you like.

e.g
    TableForm[tab1]
gives:

```
+3.033E7    +6.949E17
+1.120E3    -3.154E-2
```

and you can use:

```
Export["~/table1.tab", tab1, "Table"]
```

### Truncating

Now if you *really* insist on a hard truncate, like you did in your example, this is literally throwing away information:
`-0.0315377`$\mapsto$`-3.153E-02`

I guess you could try starting with something like:

```
truncationFormat[num_] :=
( Sign[num]*(Abs[(num *10^-(-3 + Floor@Log[10, Abs[num]]))] // 
Floor)*10.^(-3 + Floor@Log[10, Abs[num]]) // format)/;NumberQ[num]

applyTruncation[expr_] := 
 expr /. a_ :> truncationFormat[a] /; NumberQ[a]

{{5.6^10, 7.8^20}, {1120.14, -0.0315377}} // applyTruncation //TableForm
```

yielding

```
+3.033E7    +6.948E17
+1.120E3    -3.153E-2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func[x_, y_] := Module [{precisiongoal = y,
    number = x,
   b = If[x >= 0, "+", "-"]
   },  
  prova = 
   If[b == "-" , StringDrop[ StringDelete[ToString[number], "."], 1], 
    StringDelete[prova, "."]];
  decimal  = StringPosition[ prova,  n_ /; n != "0" ][[1, 1]];
  b <> StringTake[
    StringDrop[StringInsert[prova , ".", 1 + decimal], decimal - 1], 
    UpTo[precisiongoal + 1]] <> "e" <> 
   If[b == "+", ToString[ Evaluate[decimal - 1]], 
    ToString[ - Evaluate[decimal - 1]]  ]



  ]
```

it should work